# Getting the specific scroll position of div with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to fire a some code when the vertical scroll bar reaches a specific point (a specific div).

I'm having problems getting the right position of the div i'm trying to reach.

Using `scrollIntoView` works impeccably, like:

```
this.myDiv.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
```

When firing that line I get scrolled to the right place.

When I'm running a line like `document.documentElement.scrollTop` I get my current position on the Y-axis. And when I run `this.myDiv.scrollHeight` I should get the right position on the Y-axis of the div, right?

The problem is that the last line returns a number that is way too low compared with the numbers that `document.documentElement.scrollTop` returns.

My code looks something like this:

```
handleScroll = () => {
    const divScroll = this.myDiv.scrollHeight
    const currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop
    if(currentScroll >= divScroll) {
        //I reach this way too early, no where near my div at this point
    }
}


<body>
 ...

<div id="myDiv" ref={(el) => { this.myDiv = el; }}> ... </div>

</body>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the right position of the div so I can be able to tell whether the user has reached the point or not?

**Edit:**
It should be told, that the position of the div not constant. It varies for each user.

/Crellee

Comment: you need to get offset of div from document top, not its scrollHeight

Comment: Omg... of course. Thank you so much!! :-)